# How Can I Update From QT 5.5.1 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, qt

On Ubuntu 16.04, Qt 5.5.1 is included and used by default. How can I update the system so it uses a newer version, system wide by default (QT 5.7.1 for example)?

Apparently there's a bug in 5.5.1 that is causing an application I'm using to crash. I was encourages to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu, which uses a more recent version of QT. But I'd much rather update QT on Ubuntu 16.04 if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply upgrade the Qt library to a new version as such. Almost everything that depends on Qt would need to be recompiled against the newer version.

If you want a newer version, an option might be to check out the *stable* [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/faq).

It might be better to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 though, as it is an LTS and also includes Qt 5.9 which is an LTS version of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You could install Kubuntu 18.04 alongside your current OS. It comes with Qt 5.9.5. Later on, by adding the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports), users could get even newer versions depending on what [policy decision](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2018-May/011659.html) the Kubuntu Council takes.